# SQLAlchemy Join using PyBigquery to filter results

Tags: sqlalchemy, google-bigquery, pybigquery

Using a SQLAlchemy class, I'm trying to generate a query that resembles

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(non_unique_key)
FROM
  `tablename`,
  UNNEST(tasks_dns) AS dns
WHERE
  create_date_utc = TIMESTAMP("2020-12-31T23:59:59")
  AND dns LIKE "%whatever%"
```

Being an implicit join using unnest(), I don't have a clue how to construct my statement.

Using a combination of .label() and moving the unnest() call around, I've managed to move the unnest clause to either the SELECT or WHERE clauses, but not in the FROM.

For example,

```
session.query(Table.non_unique_key).filter(func.unnest(Table.dns) != '').filter(Table.create_date == "2021-04-22")
```

leaves me with

```
SELECT `tablename`.`non_unique_key` AS `tablename_non_unique_key` 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE unnest(`tablename`.`tasks_dns`) IS NOT NULL AND `tablename`.`create_date_utc` = %(create_date_utc_1)s
```

So far, using join() has just caused exceptions around not having a column to join on (which while yes, I understand what that means, I'm not sure how to get around that since an unnest is basically doing an expansion of a nested data type that doesn't have a column to join on.. which is probably where my ignorance around how to properly use SQLAlchemys join() method comes in)

Is this just a SQLAlchemy / BigQuery dialect issue at this point? Or am I just a dunce? I know the dialect library is still infant, but even with Postgres, I would have thought that this should be a somewhat common query pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional digging, I've figured it out

`Model().query().select_from(func.unnest(Model.col1).alias("whatever")).filter()....`